# Table Header View Auto Size when hide sub view

Tags: ios, dynamic, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, nstableheaderview

[image]

I have placed attached view inside tableheaderview. When there is change in template based on that SMS view 1 and/or EMail view 2 will hide un hide. I want that it should resize tableheaderview based on visible view. I have set constraints but it is not resizing headerview. can anybody guide me where i am wrong?

Comment: You can alter the height contraint at runtime

Comment: i have taken reference and tried to set it but its not working correctly

Comment: Are reloading the section ? try changing the height in heightforHeader inSection method.